# How do I update a listview with a custom adapter from another activity?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, android-listview

I am in the process of making a messaging app. So far everything is working great, however I haven't figured out how to update a listview when a new message arrives from another activity. I would like it so that if a message arrives, if the user is on the messaging screen, it will update the listview for them to show the new message.

As it is, the user has to reopen the application in order to view the new message. I am trying to figure out now how to automatically refresh or update the current listview.

My MessageAdapter is as follows:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// This is the custom adapter for displaying the labdetails in listview of a
// dialog inside the activity
String picsDownloadFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
        + "Congress" + "/", imageLinkBuilder;
private Activity activity;

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private List<MessageModel> data;
int myPosition;
int totalNumAttackers = 0, totalNumDamage = 0;
public Boolean bb[];
int element;
DbUtils dbutil;

File LocImageFile;
WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP;
List<UserModel> notificationList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

public MessageAdapter(Activity a, List<MessageModel> notifyList) {

    activity = a;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    dbutil = new DbUtils();
    // notificationList = notifyList;
    data = notifyList;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
 MessageModel array = data.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_item, null);
        viewHolder.left =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.left);
        viewHolder.right =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.right);
        viewHolder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        viewHolder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        viewHolder.txt4 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


    } else {
        // prevent recycling of views
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (array.gettype().equals("received")) {
        viewHolder.right.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.left.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.txt1.setText(array.getmsg());
        viewHolder.txt3.setText(array.getdate());
    } if (array.gettype().equals("sent")) {
        viewHolder.left.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        viewHolder.right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.txt2.setText(array.getmsg());
        viewHolder.txt4.setText(array.getdate());
    }

    return convertView;
}

// view holder class
public static class ViewHolder {

LinearLayout left,right;
TextView txt1,txt3,txt2,txt4;

}

 }
```

I have tried using:

```
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

But it keeps force closing the application.

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```